# Re-render a React App when a property is updated by a third party source

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I might be doing this the wrong way so feel free to correct me. I have a react widget (possibly several instances) running on a third party website.

I want the third party to be able to pass a session id (so the session id might not be there on initial render or might expire). So they could use the widget roughly like this:-

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="widgetone" class="react-widget" sessionid="abc"></div>
   <div id="widgettwo" class="react-widget" sessionid="def"></div>
   <div id="widgetthree" class="react-widget" sessionid="ghi"></div>
</div>
```

My index.js has code like so:-

```
const widgetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.react-widget');

widgetElements.forEach(widget => {
    // track onchange widget.attributes.sessionid.value 
    // onchange re-render so the new sessionid is passed
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App sessionid={widget.attributes.sessionid.value }/>
      </React.StrictMode>,
        div
    );
});
```

What I want is if the sessionid attribute changes value then re-render that widget. As an example. "widgetthree" loads but doesn't get its sessionid immediately. When it arrives the third party sets the sessionid attribute to the sessionid value (I then use that inside the widget to make some Api calls)

Is there a way to do this? or is there a better way I should be solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the react useEffect hook to do what you want.
This hook will rerender you app, whenever the value in the brackets is updated.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = ({ sessionid }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // What ever action you want to happen on the cahnge
    if (sessionid) {
      console.log(`updated id: "${sessionid}".`);
    }
  }, [sessionid]); // The effect will rerun whenever the session ID changes

  return (
    <div>Widget Content</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```